# GPU stops working when restarting

Tags: memory, graphics-card, motherboard, hardware-failure, gpu

I have reinstalled a computer I had abandoned for quite a while. At first it didn't show any display, so I did some basic debugging.

After switching the RAM slot connected (it has a single stick), it worked just fine. I assumed it was just the default MOBO slot and it would work from there on.

However, when turning the computer off and on again, there was no display again. I switched the RAM stick back to the slot it initially was in, and I got display again. When turning it off and on again, GPU shows no display again.

Every time I switch the RAM stick to another slot, no matter which one, I get to turn on the computer once.

Why can this be happening?

Specs:

- MOBO: MSI B360
- RAM: 1xBallistix 16GB 2400 (used to be a 2-pack, but I stole one for another build)
- CPU: i7-8700K
- GPU: MSI GTX1650 Twin Frozr 7
- Power Supply: Mars Gaming Vulcano 750W

I know the build is unbalanced, it is a frankestein that has been sitting for a long while and I now plan to use as a server.

Performed a memtest, it passed okay. Tried booting without the GPU to use CPU graphics and no display was shown regardless of RAM position. Removed BIOS battery to ensure there was no misconfiguration.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with memory training. Verify the CMOS battery is functional by replacing it.

Comment: @Ramhound I bought and installed a brand new battery, the problem was still there. Stil no graphics from the integrated on CPU and GPU only works once. I have realized that the GPU stops spinning when I reset tho.

Comment: To be honest, I don't even care about the GPU on this build at all, but I need the computer to be able to reset. I just installed the GPU because I had it spare at home. It is going to run a CLI linux server. The problem is I cant boot from the integrated graphics either.

Comment: I have just tried with another GPU (an old Gigabyte one from another PC, it doesnt even require the extra power cable) and it works just fine. Is my GPU damaged?